# On Flickr, how do I set a photo location using latitude and longitude coordinates?

Tags: flickr

On Flickr, while browsing my photostream, I can click "Add this photo to your map!" to add location information to a photo.  The "Add this photo to your map!" input field then allows locations to be entered by **name**, or by scrolling around on a map.

**How can I enter a location directly via latitude and longitude?**

Entering text like "51.7991 N 10.6156 E" does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are entering the coordinates in the wrong format.

> These are valid formats for coordinates:
>
> - `37.794721, -122.401388`
> - `37°47'41"N, 122°24'05"W`
> - `37°47'41", -122°24'05"`
> - `37°47.6833', -122°24.0833'`
> - `geo:lat=37.794721 geo:lon=-122.401388`
>
> Or you can search for addresses or landmarks, the more specific the
>   better. These are good:
>
> - 475 Sansome St, San Francisco
> - 101 Oxford Street, London
> - The London Eye
>
> And these are bad:
>
> - The West End, London
> - Adelaide, Australia
> - France

Taken from [this Flickr article on Geo Formats](http://www.flickr.com/geoformats.gne)